# Google Maps error - not showing map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get a google maps working, but first map won't load and now there is a error on a google file.

typeerror:%20a%20is%20null%20http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/pt_ALL/mapfiles/api-3/17/2/main.js%20Line%2040

This is my code:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
<script>
var map;
var zoom=5;
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(36.6, 0);

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
                zoom: zoom,
                center: center,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                minZoom: zoom
            };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

First I had the key parameter, then i took it off because it wasn't showing as well. Also I received some alert popups about the key of google maps being disabled and for me to read terms and conditions of google maps, which i did and found my website to comply to current terms (login website without users paying any fee.) of google maps.

I would greatly appreciate any help with this issue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, div id is `map_canvas` but you are using `map-canvas` in your js code. 
Second, try giving dimensions in pixels instead of percents i.e `width:400px;height:400px;`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/x8dSP/3421/

CSS:

```
#map_canvas {
     width:500px;
     height:500px;
 }
```

JS:

```
var map;
var zoom = 5;
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(36.6, 0);

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: zoom,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        minZoom: zoom
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Demo doesn't exist !

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi Jsfiddle seems to have removed the old fiddle. anyway, the relevant code is still present in the answer. You may try it in a editor and check.